Text truncated when setting spacing in SwiftUI
I created a view for card. But whenever I try to add 20px spacing between first text (Heading) and middle text (description) limit to 3 lines and button, the middle text automatically truncated. I used bottom padding but same.
I want button position should not be changed and middle text limit I set to 3 lines.
How can I add spacing with static position of button? Many thanks for help.
Code:
struct CardView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Constants
    private struct ViewConstants {
        static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        static let cardWidth = screenWidth - 100
        static let cardRatio = 300.0/377.0
        static let cardHeight = cardWidth/cardRatio + 10
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                LottieView(filename: "Animation", animationType: .loop)
                    .frame(height: ViewConstants.cardHeight / 2)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("CARD SHOPPING")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                    
                    Text("The all-in-one solution to buy all the smartphones, laptops and tablets in your house. Many ")
                        .lineLimit(3)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("sign up bin tapped")
                }) {
                    Text("Click for more")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                }
                .padding(.top, 4)
                .padding(.bottom, 24)
                
            }
            .frame(width: ViewConstants.cardWidth, height: ViewConstants.cardHeight)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .cornerRadius(12)
        }
        .padding(.leading, -20 * 3)
    }
}


Needs spacing:

Text truncated:


If you add padding, then the height is going to grow. But the height of the inner VStack is being fixed to ViewConstants.cardHeight, so when the space runs out, the text is truncated. To fix, just remove the fixed height from the VStack. BTW, UIScreen.main is deprecated, suggest using a GeometryReader if you need to measure the screen height.

Add .minimumScaleFactor(0.5) to the Text and it won't truncate that easily anymore. Instead the size of Text will be smaller when SwiftUI needs more space.
Alternatively you can add .layoutPriority(1) to the Text to tell SwiftUI that it has priority (in allocating space to it). Let me know if this helps.
